# Why does min-width doesn't work on svg, and because of svg the paragraphs behave oddly?

Tags: html, css

Why the svg does not change its width but the paragraphs do.
Also, why do the paragraphs fit the svg's width instead of having the defined width from my css-file.
When I change the order and bring the svg after the paragraphs then the width of the paragraphs is the same as in my css-file. 
https://jsfiddle.net/daotwLg3/

```
    <style>
main{
background-color: lightblue;
max-width:600px;
padding:1rem;

}

main p{
margin: 1px auto;
background-color: white;
padding:1rem;
}

.rectangle{
  stroke-width:3;
  stroke:black;
  fill:black;
}

main svg{
  border:3px solid blue;
  max-width:600px;


}

main div{
  max-width:600px;
}

main p:nth-child(1){
  width:1000px;
}

main p:nth-child(2){
  max-width:800px;

}    
</style>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
        <title>Modus Energy</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
        <main>

<div>
            <svg width="500px" height="500px" viewbox="0 0 500 500">
                <rect class="rectangle" x="250" y="250" width="100px" height="100px"></rect>
            </svg>
</div>
        <p>Notice that you're not naming lines with this syntax, just areas. When you use this syntax the lines on either end of the areas are actually getting named automatically. If the name of your grid area is foo, the name of the area's starting row line and starting column line will be foo-start, and the name of its last row line and last column line will be foo-end. This means that some lines might have multiple names, such as the far left line in the above example, which will have three names: header-start, main-start, and footer-start.</p>
        <p>Notice that you're not naming lines with this syntax, just areas. When you use this syntax the lines on either end of the areas are actually getting named automatically. If the name of your grid area is foo, the name of the area's starting row line and starting column line will be foo-start, and the name of its last row line and last column line will be foo-end. This means that some lines might have multiple names, such as the far left line in the above example, which will have three names: header-start, main-start, and footer-start.</p>


    </main>
<script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For your SVG, ensure you also include `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` in your opening tag, as otherwise behaviour can become unpredictable. You might also want to remove the `px` from your width and height of your rectangle, to prevent the SVG from requiring that size render.

Comment: Still not sure the output you are expecting out of it.

Answer (score 0):

You never use min-width. Try:

```
main svg
{
   border:3px solid blue;
   min-width: 600px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you, but the minimum/maximum size of svg elements can be set via css function `max(<min-value>, <value>)` / `min(<value>, <max-value>)` respectively.

For example, for the dynamic width of the **rect** element, I did this:

`width: max(6px, var(--width-percentage));`